# How to prove that $x \mapsto \log(1+e^{-x})$ is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

How to prove that $x \mapsto \log(1+e^{-x})$ is a convex function?

I have tried with the basic definition of convex function, i.e., $f(ax+by) \leq af(x)+bf(y)$, but was not able to solve further.

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Did you sketch the graph?

Comment: I have tried with the basic definition of convex function..... like f(ax+by) <= af(x)+bf(y)..  but not able to solve furhter.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** it is a fact that if a function is twice differentiable and has positive second derivative everywhere, then it is convex.

Comment: can i prove it with the basic definition of convex function ?

Comment: I don't think it will be easy.. You have to check that $$\log(1+e^{-(tx+(1-t)y)})\leq t \log(1-e^{-x})+(1-t)\log(1+e^{-y}).$$
Maybe trying to reverse engineering it gets you something.

Comment: I have tried it by first expanding log(1+x) series and then to simplify I have taken the log of both sides... but it's giving me 0=0.

Comment: It is not an equivalence, since a convex function is continuous for sure but not necessarily twice differentiable. Consider, for instance, $f(x)=|x|$ or $f(x)=|x|^3$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for pointing. I have rephrased it.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\log(1+e^{-x}) = \frac{-e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}} = -\frac{1}{e^x+1} $$
is an increasing function, since $e^x$ is an increasing function.

This gives that $\log(1+e^{-x})$ is a convex function.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\me{{\rm e}}$Actually, it is a **strictly convex** function, since its second derivative  $f''(x)=\me^x/(1+\me^x)^2$, is **positive everywhere**.

If you want to prove its strict convexity by the definition, you need to play with the mean value theorem several times, following the same routine to prove that positivity of the second derivative is sufficient (but not necessary) for strict convexity.